# Vaadin: Moving window into corner after opening

Tags: window, positioning, vaadin

I have a new window with undefined size. How to place it into right bottom corner in the page? The getWidth() and getHeight() functions return -1, because I didnt set them by setWidth() and setHeight(). 
I dont want to set them to keep the size depending on the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Window.setPositionX()` to change the horizontal offset from the LEFT border, and `setPositionY()` for offset from TOP. Unfortunately there is no way to set offset from RIGHT/BOTTOM. So unless you know the width/height of both your window and the main window, this is not possible through Vaadin server calls (as far as I know).

However you can solve it through CSS: define a style name e.g. `mywindow` using `addStyleName("mywindow")` and then make a CSS rule like this:

```
.v-window.v-widget.mywindow { 
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: It is useful piece of knowledge for me, but not usable for my problem. It makes subsequent moving and resizing impossible. I'd like to set initial position only. Is there an event like "onRepaint"? After the window has been shown the style name should be removed.

Comment: I found addFocusListener, but when I click on the window title (focus is triggered) and remove the style, the window jumps to the UI center. Is there a way to prevent moving?

Comment: Resizing would not be a problem as the window would remain bottom-right and resize toward top-left. Moving is a problem though.

Comment: Resizing is problem too in case of right-bottom position because vaadin-window has resize-control only in right-bottom corner. I need move it at first.